# Ошибка ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#

Если ничего не выбрано, то при нажатии на кнопку DelBut выскакивает ошибка

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "InvalidArgument=Значение '-1'
>   недопустимо для 'index'.

Имя параметра: index

вот код

```
    private void StartGame_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void FinishBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FinishGame.Items.Add(StartGame.SelectedIndex);
        StartGame.Items.RemoveAt(StartGame.SelectedIndex);
    }

    private void AddBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GameName.Text == "" || StartGame.Items.Contains(GameName.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Текст ошибки", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            StartGame.Items.Add(GameName.Text);
            GameName.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void GameName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void FinishGame_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void DelBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if () //
        {
            StartGame.Items.RemoveAt(StartGame.SelectedIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: ну а что вы хотите удалять, если ничего не выбрано?

Comment: У вас нет проверки на значение `SelectedIndex`. Валидное значение этого параметра любое целое положительное число включая ноль. У вас же при нажатии на кнопку `StartGame.SelectedIndex` возвращает `-1` а в списке элементов индексы начинаются всегда с нуля. Просто добавьте проверку индекса на `>= 0`.

Comment: как прописать проверку на выбранного значения?
if (StartGame.SelectedItems.Count != 0)    подойдёт такое?

Answer (score 0):

нашёл!

```
 if (StartGame.SelectedItems.Count != 0) // проверка на наличие выбранного эллемента
```